# Accelerometer data reversed in iphone 5?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios6, iphone-5

I'm creating a cocos2d game on iOS that uses the accelerometer.  I just started testing on an iphone 5 and for some reason, it's reversing the accelerometer data - basically it behaves as if the screen orientation is 180 degrees flipped from how it actually is, tilting down causes it to send things up, left goes right etc.

It works fine on my iphone 4 running iOS 5 and on both my ipad running iOS 5 and my ipad running iOS 6.  Not sure if it's an issue with just the iphone 5 or all iphones running iOS 6.

I can't find any mention of this issue online, wondering if anyone else is running into this and if you know of a solution.

Comment: Have you implemented the new rotation methods for iOS6? It might have something to do with that. https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v2/templates/Xcode4_templates/cocos2d%20iOS.xctemplate/AppDelegate.m

Comment: The code you linked to seems to be for cocos2d 2 yes?  I'm having the most nightmarish time trying to upgrade to 2.  Is there a solution that works for 1.1?

Comment: Yeah, try the 1.1 template. https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop/templates/Xcode4_templates/cocos2d.xctemplate/AppDelegate.m

Comment: Hm.  That was only one line of code different from what I already had, but I made that change.  Still backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out what was going on.  In iOS 6 the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method is deprecated and no longer gets called.  I had code in there to do two things - detect which landscape orientation the phone was loading into and adjust the variables accordingly, and to prevent the phone from flipping the orientation during gameplay (it's a tilt-to-move game).  The reason everything was behaving as if the view was upside-down was because it was, and the phone's orientation was locked, and my code to correct for that wasn't being called.  [Here's what Apple says about willRotateToInterfaceOrientation](http://www.bgr.com/2012/07/16/ios-6-download-beta-3-change-log/):

> The willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:,
>   willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, and
>   didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: methods are no longer called on any
>   view controller that makes a full screen presentation over itself—for
>   example, by calling presentViewController:animated:completion:. You
>   should make sure that your apps are not using these methods to manage
>   the layout of any subviews. Instead, they should use the view
>   controller’s viewWillLayoutSubviews method and adjust the layout using
>   the view’s bounds rectangle.

Now I just need to figure out how to use the willLayoutSubviews method to replicate my original functionality.